# Angular2 testing - Get element by Id

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular2 test component and i've noticed this line in the tutorials:

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
```

`de` is defined as `DebugElement` type.

How can I get `DebugElement` by id?

That may seem extremely simple but I can't find any direction in the docs.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can also use [by.css](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md)

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#theid'));
```

Comment: I'm getting: TypeError: platform_browser_1.By.id is not a function

Comment: Have you tried using the hash for the by.css selector id?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll remove the first part that must not work on Angular2.

Comment: What does the call to `.debugElement.nativeElement` return?

Comment: @AdamHughes It looks like someone else edited this today and the review has been accepted. I'm looking into if it should have been accepted. The answer to your question though is that it returns a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: I was able to get the same results using `.debugElement` instead of `.debugElement.nativeElement` ... ie the return was a button that had a disabled attribute.

Thank you for this answer as well, saved my day

Comment: @AdamHughes

Yes, that's how I had it, if you review the revision here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41399194/revisions you will see that. I'm looking into if there is a prefered method.

Comment: @AdamHughes looking into it looks like that it shouldn't be used in this case so the change should have never been accepted by the people reviewing. I've reverted it back.

Comment: If anyone gets tripped by the `By is not defined` error, this import might help: `import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";`

Comment: `Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '#1' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: do not forget to:
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
if you are doing the tests in Angular >2

Answer (score 28):

```
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
```

- using id

  `expect(compiled.querySelector('#from').textContent).toContain('From Date');`
- using css

  `expect(compiled.querySelector('.from').textContent).toContain('From Date');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use following syntax to get an attribute value from an HTML element:

To retrieve an HTML element:

```
const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('name of element'); // example a, h1, p
```

To get an attribute value from that element:

```
const attributeValue = element.attributeName // like textContent/href
```